# React.js -- LinkContainer. Prevent link from navigating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically what I want to do should be simple :)

I have a two links in the menu, Link1 and Link2.

Link1 has a checkboxes. If no checkbox is selected I need to prevent navigation to Link2.

Inside < Nav > I have this code:

```
 <LinkContainer activeClassName='active'
                       to={{pathname: '/cleanup/manual/' + this.state.ProjectId, query: {productIds: this.state.ProductIDs.join()}}}><NavItem
          eventKey={3} onClick={ this.onNavItemClick }title='Sop'>Link2</NavItem></LinkContainer>
```

When hovered with the mouse, the link is structured like this (no checkbox selected):

```
http://localhost:3000/#/cleanup/manual/39?productIds=
```

And when I have selected some checkboxes:

```
http://localhost:3000/#/cleanup/manual/39?productIds=62%2C63
```

I have access to the state where I can see if I have and ProductIDs selected, and this is how I tried to do it:

```
handleSelect(event) {   
if (event === 3 && this.state.ProductIDs.length === 0) {
    NotificationManager.warning('Please select some products');
    this.setState({activeKey: 0});
    return;
}



this.setState({activeKey: event});
},
```

If statement works just fine, but it always navigates to the Link2 page. How can I prevent it from navigating there?

Comment: Have you tried using event's `preventDefault()` in the `onNavItemClick` method ?

Comment: I have forgot about that. Problem solved. Can you please make an answer so I accept it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want `e.preventDefault()` in `onNavItemClick` to prevent the default functionality from occurring.